# Mysql in spring framework MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have some problems in mapper.xml from spring framework

it is failed:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'where ut.catalog_id = 1  and ut.title like CONCAT('%','d','%')'` at line 4

Code:

```
<select id="tListSearch" resultType="TalentBoardVO">
    select * 
    from user_talents ut
    left outer join catalog c
    on ut.catalog_id = c.id

    <include refid="search"></include>

    order by ut.id desc
    limit #{pageStart}, #{perPageNum}
</select>
```

this is inclue tag

```
   <sql id="search">
    <if test="searchType != null">

        <if test="searchType == 'g'.toString()">
            where ut.catalog_id = 1
            and ut.title like CONCAT('%', #{keyword}, '%')
        </if>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be much better if you can show us your whole SQL query.

If you are using MyBatis framework, this is what you can do.
Good practice is you should separate 2 variables that you want to compare in WHERE statement.

```
<sql id ="search">
    <where>
        <if test ="idCatalog" != null">
            AND ut.catalog_id = #{idCatalog}
        </if>
        <if test="searchType != null">
            <bind name="searchTypeLike" value="'%' + searchType + '%'" />
            AND ut.title LIKE #{searchTypeLike}
        </if>
    </where>
</sql>
```